# incompatible clusterID Hadoop swarm

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

anytime I rebooted the swarm I have this problem

```
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /hadoop/dfs/data: 
namenode clusterID = CID-b25a0845-5c64-4603-a2cb-d7878c265f44; 
datanode clusterID = CID-f90183ca-4d87-4b49-8fb2-ca642d46016c at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:777)

FATAL datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> 
(Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to namenode/10.0.0.7:8020. Exiting.  
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:574)
```

I solved this problem by deleting this docker volume

> sudo docker volume inspect hadoop_datanode

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-05-10T19:35:31Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "hadoop"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/data0/docker_var/volumes/hadoop_datanode/_data",
        "Name": "hadoop_datanode",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

But in this volume are present the files which I put in hdfs, so in this way, I have to put again the files into hdfs when I deploy the swarm. I'm not sure this is the right way to solve this problem. 
Googling I found one solution but I don't know how to applicate it before the swarm reboot, this is the solution:

> *The problem is with the property name dfs.datanode.data.dir, it is misspelt as dfs.dataode.data.dir. This invalidates the property from
>   being recognised and as a result, the default location of
>   ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/hadoop-${USER}/dfs/data is used as data directory.
>   hadoop.tmp.dir is /tmp by default, on every reboot the contents of
>   this directory will be deleted and forces datanode to recreate the
>   folder on startup. And thus Incompatible clusterIDs. Edit this
>   property name in hdfs-site.xml before formatting the namenode and
>   starting the services.*

I use this docker hub for namenode:
bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8

and this for datanode:
bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried mounting a volume from host (outside container) to `/tmp` dir in docker? In that case it wouldn't be deleted on every reboot.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I tried a inspect the path of volume and in this path I found a file where is write the cluster namenode ID. I removed that  and after this I rebooted the swarm and I haven't more the problem to delete the volume, but the files into hdfs are not more present because when I navigate the HDSF is empty. Yes i use this way but the files are must present when the datanode into HDFS that are whenever rebooted. 
Thanks

Comment: This worked for me:
docker-compose down &&
docker volume ls &&
docker volume prune